# javascriptでbodyタグ内に対してtableを追加しているはずなのに、画面には何も表示されません

Tags: javascript, html

javascriptでbodyタグ内に対してtableを追加しているはずなのに、画面には何も表示されないのですが、原因が掴めません。
画面にtableが表示されない原因の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

javascriptのソースは、

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var url = "http://ooo";
$.get(url, function (json) {

    var table = $('<table/>');

    for (var i in json) {
        var tr = $('<tr/>')
        var td1 = $('<td/>').text(json[i].年);
        var td2 = $('<td/>').text(json[i].名前);
        var td3 = $('<td/>').text(json[i].読み);
        tr.append(td1).append(td2).append(td3);
        table.append(tr);
    }

    $("body").append(table);

  });
});
```

htmlのソース(ヘッダーは必要項目以外省略)は、

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

となっています。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `json`の中身を提示できますか？

Comment: すいません、jsonデータを呼び出すキーを間違えていました

Comment: ブラウザの開発ツールを使っていますか？（chromeのデベロッパーツールなど
上記の内容であれば、デベロッパーツールのコンソール上でエラーの追跡がすぐ出来たと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsonの呼出しキーを間違えていました。
解決しました。